Wording: Latex compiler and auxiliary tools
Two questions about wording:

is there a term meaning any of lualatex, xelatex and pdflatex? Possibly more than that ... someone denoted *latex?
Is the correct word 'latex compiler'?

What about all these auxiliary tools interacting with a latex compiler like bibtex, biber, makeindex, makeglossaries, pythontex and many others:? Is there a common word for all of them?



That properly depends on the context in which you are referring to them.

lualatex, xelatex, and pdflatex are symbolic links to the TeX engines LuaTeX, XeTeX, and PdfTeX which load a precompiled format (LaTeX). So if anything I'd say engine is the most common name for the three. And auxiliary tools sounds fine.

Maybe a better word for all of them is Programs  or executables!

@Skillmon: Engine, yes I think this is good. refers also to the precompiled format.
This is common use and not self-invented. For the other tools... Not so sure.. programs hm.. .are all executables also.
I am watching out for a term which distinguishes between engines and 'auxiliary' executables.

'helper programmes' gets used a lot in less technical guidance. 'engine' doesn't 'refer also to the precompiled format'. engines and formats are distinct. the same engine can load different formats. the same format may be loaded by different engines. what the engine pdftex does depends on the name it is called by, as well as any options given. if you call pdflatex, you get something different from what you get if you call pdftex. it's the same engine, but it loads a different format.
